# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel having "bad value" as default parameters

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop, automation

I'm trying to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. It seems to load fine but when I try to use it, all the defaults parameters are not working. Here is a screenshot that shows all those bad values

[image]

Whenever I try to ommit them, the compiler tells me that the function needs more than 1 parameter.

This function is Open as in :

```
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
   Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("ss.xlsx");
```

How can I use the default value for those 14 parameters?

EDIT
I'm using C# 3.5 (2008) with Office 2010

Accepted Solution :

Type.Missing works
I also had this issue http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;320369
The problem is that my windows is french but office is in english so hell breaks loose.

Solution is

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US"); 
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

Comment: "Whenever I try to omit them" - But you are omitting them, or posting the wrong code. And which C# version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `System.Type.Missing` or `System.Reflection.Missing.Value` for any parameters you want to ommit.

But it looks like you are using wrong (Lower) version Excel Interop to open "xlsx" (should use version 12 for office 2007 support)

Comment: I tried both but none of them works. I get some kind of InvalidData error

Answer (score 1):

Use Type.Missing for the optional parameters you don't want to set.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx
and
http://softwaresalariman.blogspot.com/2010/05/rudimentary-c-com-interop-client-for.html